# Считывание строк из файла

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня 2 вопроса: 1 - как считать целую строку? 2 - как считать только третью строку? Первая переменная типа `int` остальные `std::string`. Из скриншота видно, что считывание происходит по словам и разделителем переменных служит пробел.

Код программы:

```
#include <windows.h> // кириллица
#include <iostream.h> // ввод-вывод
#include <cstdlib> // конвертация
#include <string> // строка
#include <fstream> // чтение-запись


int unp_consignee; // унп грузополучателя
std::string consignee; // грузополучатель
std::string the_goods_to_delivery_have_accepted; // товар к доставке принял
std::string by_proxy; // по доверенности
std::string give_out; // выданной
std::string the_consignee_has_accepted; // принял грузополучатель

if (settings_txt_reading.is_open()) {
    settings_txt_reading >> unp_consignee;
    settings_txt_reading >> consignee;
    settings_txt_reading >> the_goods_to_delivery_have_accepted;
    settings_txt_reading >> by_proxy;
    settings_txt_reading >> give_out;
    settings_txt_reading >> the_consignee_has_accepted;
}
```

Данные текстового файла:

```
20
dfgdf dfgdfg
dfgdfg dfg3 
dfgdf344 44 
sdfsd55
66 66 67
```

Comment: Добавьте код и данные в виде текста в вопрос. В текущем виде его скорее всего закроют.

Comment: `std::getline ( settings_txt_reading, consignee);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтение из потока ввода (например, консоли или файла) через оператор `>>` обеспечивает чтение до первого символа пробельной группы (пробел, перевод строки, таб).

Если нужно считать целую строку вместе с пробелами можно использовать функцию [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). В Вашем случае будет примерно так:

```
std::getline(settings_txt_reading, consignee);
```

Чтобы считать третью строку, нужно сначала считать первые две, проигнорировать их, а после считать нужную. Сразу считать третью не получится, т.к. нужно как-то определить где же эта строка начинается. Если бы строки были фиксированной длины, то можно было бы использовать [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) для позиционирования на конкретном байте.